# Problem deserializing objects from cache on MyBatis 3/Java

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, classpath, mybatis

So I'm working on a side project using MySQL/MyBatis3/Tomcat.  I'm currently working on turning on caching in MyBatis.  When I first tried to turn on caching, I got exceptions due to the fact that my object didn't implement Serializable.  So, after implementing Serializable with the object I was trying to cache; it appeared to cache fine.

But; when I hit my servlet a second time with the same situation, and the object mapper attempts to deserialize my object from the cache, I get the following stack trace:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error deserializing object.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.MyClass
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error deserializing object.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.MyClass
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:8)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:77)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:69)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForList(MapperMethod.java:85)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:65)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:38)
at $Proxy5.selectAllArgs(Unknown Source)
```

The other thing I don't understand is this:

```
Serializable result;
try {
  ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) value);
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);

  // LINE THROWING EXCEPTION IN org.apache.ibatis.cache.decorators.SerializedCache
  result = (Serializable) ois.readObject();
  // -- -----------------------------------

  ois.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new CacheException("Error deserializing object.  Cause: " + e, e);
}
return result;
```

Why is it even trying to load the class to begin with?  It just needs to cast to Serializable.  Its worth noting that when I don't have caching turned on; everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, reason this happened was because I had my project in Eclipse set up incorrectly and this resulted in some classes not being available when my server started.  Basically, all I did was change my build output directory from "workspace/project/build" to "workspace/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/build".  I'm going to read more about proper servlet deployment now....