# MyBatis cant find my classes - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, mybatis, wsimport

I have an EAR application for web service operation. When I started to implement caching, I got ClassNotFoundException from ASURLClassLoader. In another question some user gave me a hint, that MyBatis can't see my classes (generated by wsimport).

Please if you are interested, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979225/classnotfoundexception-when-deserializing-data-from-cache) for brief details of EAR structure and thrown exception.

How can I make MyBatis see my classes? I tried to add following line to my EJB constructor, but it did not help.

```
Resources.setDefaultClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

I found some clue in question [Problem deserializing objects from cache on MyBatis 3/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893668/problem-deserializing-objects-from-cache-on-mybatis-3-java), but I have no web application and have no WebContent folder. Where should be my classes generated?

Thank you

Worsik

Comment: Problem solved after downloading mybatis 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with mybatis 3.2.2 library.
Thanks to Stephen C from original question.